# NodeJS upload to Google Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

So I am using Google Storage sample code to upload a mp3 file to the server however an error keeps accoring

```
Error: Not Found
    at Gaxios._request (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/XXXXX-Server/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:89:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async JWT.requestAsync (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/XXXXX-Server/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:343:18)
    at async Upload.makeRequest (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/XXXXX-Server/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:320:21)
    at async Upload.createURIAsync (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/XXXX-Server/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:145:22)
```

This is the code (as you can see it is the Google Sample code)

```
 // Process the file upload and upload to Google Cloud Storage.
app.post('/upload', multer.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.file) {
      res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
      return;
    }
  
    // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
    const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
  
    blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
      next(err);
    });
  
    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
      // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
      const publicUrl = format(
        `https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/${blob.name}`
      );
      res.status(200).send(publicUrl);
    });
  
    blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
  });
```

Comment: Seems like `bucket.file(req.file.originalname)` this only creates a blob from the name of the file not the file itself.

Comment: Please edit the question to show which line of code generates that error. It might also help to explain how you are invoking this code.

Comment: is this "Google Storage sample code" in some tutorial? can we have a link to the source?